# Javascript errors window.setInterval

Tags: javascript, error-handling

i programmed a dashboard which is responses to userinput. For example there is an expertmode where experienced users with our models can add advanced stuff. The expert mode shall only be shown if a user checked "show expert mode".

My Code works, but produces a lot of errors:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("expertmodus").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("allbranches").querySelector(".col-sm-6").className = "col-sm-4";
    document.getElementById("Mitte").querySelector(".col-sm-6").className = "col-sm-4";
  } else {}
}, 1);

window.setInterval(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("expertmodus").checked == false) {
    document.getElementById("allbranches").querySelector(".col-sm-4").className = "col-sm-6";
    document.getElementById("Mitte").querySelector(".col-sm-4").className = "col-sm-6";
  } else {}
}, 1);
```

This is my code, it´s pretty simple. How would an experienced programmer with javascript handle this?

Best regards
Markus

Comment: why 2 timeouts ? why not if(check) { doStuff } else { doStuff } ?

Comment: Be careful with the intervals you've written. This code is executed each millisecond.

Comment: The above code does not follow conventional logic. If `document.getElementById` already identifies only that element in your application, why using the `querySelector` as well? Beside the `setInterval` functionality here...what does the else statement do there? 
please send a self-contained [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is an R-Shiny App. I guess the Code will not make sense here.

```
materialSwitch(inputId = "expertmodus", label = "Experteneinstellungen sind ausgeblendet", status = "primary", right = TRUE)
```